# Stop Timer Within Try Catch

Tags: c#, .net, timer, try-catch

Not sure why this isn't working. I have a timer defined, which runs a method every 2 seconds. Within that method I have a try/catch. Try to execute this code, catch should disable the timer and then display a message box. For some reason my message box displays over and over every 2 seconds. Why won't my timer disable?

```
    Timer timer1 = new Timer();

    public MainForm()
    {
        timer1.Interval = 2000;
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(OnTimer);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        //More code
    }

    private void OnTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Code
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Message");
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            this.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Thanks. -Jason

Comment: Could you post the minimal code sample that reproduces the problem (i.e. replace `// Code` with real code)?

Comment: Sorry for the //Code, but the code within the try didn't matter. My question was about the catch. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `MessageBox.Show("Message")` is blocking execution of `timer1.Enabled = false;` because it is a modal dialog. Try disabling the timer so it won't keep on firing the OnTimer callback first, before displaying the modal dialog:

```
private void OnTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Code
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Message");
        this.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew it was something stupid that I just wasn't seeing. Thanks a ton!!!

Answer (score 0):

This will help you understand...

```
Timer timer1 = new Timer();

public MainForm()
{
    timer1.Interval = 2000;
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(OnTimer);
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    //More code
}

private void OnTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Now the catch executes!  Poof!");
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Message");
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        this.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Perhaps you meant to do this?

```
private void OnTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // code
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Message");
        this.Dispose();
    }
    finally
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Bonjin Li is correct. The MessageBox was blocking the timer1.Enabled = false.

Answer (score -3):

Your try has nothing in it, so there isn't anything that's going to fail to throw you to the catch.

If you do have some code in there, you're sure its throwing an exception and hitting the catch?

Comment: The try block contains the comment `// Code`, which means that there actually is code in the try.